# How to download my div of chart as image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I have a chart I am downloading it using external library as image but it is not downloading correctly .

I am using the following code

```
 <a id="downloadImage">
  <img src="~/Content/images/imgae-icon.jpg" alt="" />
 </a>
 <div id="InflationChart" style="height: 400px;"> </div>
 <div id="previewImage" hidden></div>
```

The `InflationChart` div contains the actual chart. as below

[image: Actual Chart Image]

I am using javascript code to download this div as image .

```
$("#downloadImage").on('click', function () {
    element = $("#InflationChart");
    html2canvas(element, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
            getCanvas = canvas;
        }
    });
    var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
    var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
    $("#downloadImage").attr("download", "image.png").attr("href", newData);
});
```

The donloaded image is not as actual image . the downloaded image is below

[image: Downloaded Image]

Comment: Most JS libraries that make charts (like ChartJS or ApexCharts) support exporting an image (natively from the library) without having to use html2canvas. Have you tried that already?

[ApexCharts] https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/toolbar/#download
[ChartJS] https://quickchart.io/documentation/chart-js/image-export/